# How to Update innerHtml of a cell On Separate Pages

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have a footer on my website  that lists the date last updated.

```
<footer>
        <table class="foot">
            <tr>
                <th>Contact information:</th>
                <th>Date Last Updated:</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>email address</td>
                <td>November 31, 2014</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </footer>
```

As you can see the date is hard coded and this has to be changed each time I update the site. The site however is made up of 15 different pages and each one need to be updated because the footer is on everyone of them.

Is there a way to update the date on all the pages if I only update the information on the homepage using javascript. If so how?

Thank you

I was wondering

Answer (score 0):

Changing the date on the home page might not be the best idea.

Instead create a new (maybe json or even just plain text) file to store the date. Then read this file on every page and put the content into your footer.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are part of a solution, you can Replace All in Entire Solution with Visual Studio.  If you can connect to a database, you can store the date last modified there, and just call to it from your pages - then you can just update database field when you update the content.  Otherwise, you can store it in a separate file and call that for the date.

Short answer: Probably not, but there are other ways to skin a cat.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file "global.js" to include on every page...

inside global.js:

```
window.onload = updateDate;

function updateDate() {
    displaydate = "November 31st, 1999";
    fd = document.getElementById('footerdate');
    fd.innerHTML = displaydate;
}
```

include that file on every page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="global.js"></script>
```

change your footer to be:

```
<footer>
    <table class="foot">
        <tr>
            <th>Contact information:</th>
            <th>Date Last Updated:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>email address</td>
            <td id="footerdate"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</footer>
```

Then you can just update the date in the global.js and it will carry through to all pages every time.

Answer (score 0):

Put the date in a separate html file, then display it using an `<iFrame>` inside the `<td>`.